# Can I populate Google Sheets cells adjacent to a target cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, regexextract

I have a maintenance tracker in Google Sheets for lighting fixtures. One column is a type of fixture "B", the column adjacent is the problem "C". I'd like to find specific fixtures by name and copy the adjacent data into a different sheet.
Basically, I need to find a specific cell and populate a different cell with adjacent data of that cell.

Comment: question is not clear. share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: i've clarified, also, here is my link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16YVodbFhjPB_DlWYb47wgN5pGIBtXJoo4fz4O0l185Y/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

- try simple **`VLOOKUP`** with exact and partial matches and outputting 1st and 2nd adjacent cells

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(""&B2:B, 
   {REGEXEXTRACT(Maintenance!B8:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)), Maintenance!C8:D}, 
   {2, 3}, 0)))
  ```

[image: 0]